# Jtable jquery expand Child table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using Jquery Jtable, I need to expand a child table (I have the "master" row ID).

 How can I achieve this? 
I would like to show a child table expanded, not collapse as is shown as default.

Thanks,Nk

Comment: Try calling the [openChildTable](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-openChildTable) method on loading jTable

Comment: I tried `$('#MyTable').jtable('openChildTable',$row);` after `$('#MyTable').jtable('load');` but it does not work

Comment: You need to specify the third argument (callback handler) that is called by jTable when the child table is shown (After opening animation is finished, as shown in the documentation)

Comment: Already tried but it is not working

Comment: If possible could you update your question with a jFiddle of what you have tried so far, other SO users may be able to chip in with help as I cannot make up much from what you have just presented?

Answer (score 3):

Trigger the click event:
`$('#divTable').jtable('getRowByKey',1).find("img").trigger('click');`

Comment: If you are using a `<span>` use click()
`$('#divTable').jtable('getRowByKey',1).find("span").click();`